# Problem with loading billions of records into Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

In carrying out the PoC I would like to really load hudge of data to Apache Ignite with enabled native persistency from parquet via spark application.
Recently I’ve processes tests to load about 5 billions record. Ultimately, there would be around 100 billion records to load on a production environment using larger hardware.
The conclusions I have from this experiment:
Loading initially ran at 150,000 records per second. This satisfied me initially. Unfortunately, after the first few iterations of loading, after 200 million records had been loaded, the rating started to drop dramatically to 5,000 records per second. Each subsequent loading only got longer. Single loading iteration contains about 100 million records. I was therefore forced to load the data into new caches, e.g.: READINGS_202204, READINGS_202205, and so on. Data on a monthly basis.
I would not be able to load all the data into one cache. I have some suspicion that the cause may be a single index.bin file that is not partitioned as opposed to data files that are partitioned. Ignite increases the time to search of the index during the loading of subsequent batches of data. This is my guess.
Therefore, I had to load the year's readings into twelve READINGS_ cache objects as I wrote above.

**Question:**
Is it possible to load, for example, 5 billion records into one cache so that loading does not slow down drastically after loading 200 million records? Given the following three physical nodes. Maybe I need a lot more physical nodes for this task?

**My cluster specification:**
3 x worker
Each worker has: 16 Core, 96 GB RAM, 6 x 900GB HDD, Net card 1Gb/s). Yes. I have HDD not SDD.

**Some important settings:**

- 2048 partitions
- Disabled WAL
- Enabled direct I/O
- checkpointPageBufferSize = 4GB
- Enabled Native persistency

I’ve problems with Pages Write Throttling and had to set the parameter „writeThrottlingEnabled”. At the moment, backup is not important to me.

I’ve created five instance Ignite server per node. Totally is 15 Ignite server instances on three physically worker nodes.

I attach below the relevant parts of the config file from one of worker nodes:

```
<beans>
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="gridName" value="an-ignite-grid"/>
        <property name="localHost" value="192.168.100.11"/>
        <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="20000"/>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="socketWriteTimeout" value="5000"/>
                <property name="localPort" value="48100"/>
                <property name="usePairedConnections" value="true"/>
                <!--<property name="connectionsPerNode" value="6"/>-->
                <!-- <property name="connectionsPerNode" value="10"/>-->
                <!-- <property name="usePairedConnections" value="true"/>-->
                <!-- <property name="socketReceiveBuffer" value="#{64L * 1024}"/>-->
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <!-- Initial local port to listen to. -->
                <property name="localPort" value="48500"/>
                <!-- Changing local port range. This is an optional action. -->
                <property name="localPortRange" value="50"/>
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>192.168.100.11:48500..48550</value>
                                <value>192.168.100.12:48500..48550</value>
                                <value>192.168.100.13:48500..48550</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="workDirectory" value="/data2/ignite/work"/>
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="pageSize" value="#{4096 * 2}"/>
                <property name="walMode" value="NONE"/>
                <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{128 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="checkpointThreads" value="6"/>
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
                        <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                    <list>
                        <!--
                        Large erea memory region with eviction enabled.
                        -->
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                            <property name="name" value="Region_Eviction"/>
                            <!-- Memory region of 512 MB initial size. -->
                            <property name="initialSize" value="#{512 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                            <!-- Maximum size is 8 GB. -->
                            <property name="maxSize" value="#{8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                            <!-- Enabling eviction for this memory region. -->
                            <!-- <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/> -->
                            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                            <!-- Increasing the buffer size to 4 GB. -->
                            <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <!--<property name="groupName" value="group1"/>-->
                    <property name="name" value="READINGS_202204"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="sqlSchema" value="PUBLIC"/>
                    <!-- enable disk page compression for this cache -->
                    <property name="diskPageCompression" value="SNAPPY"/>
                    <property name="dataRegionName" value="Region_Eviction"/>
                    <!-- Number of backup copies -->
                    <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                    <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="false"/>
                    <property name="affinity">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                            <property name="partitions" value="2048"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="keyConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheKeyConfiguration">
                            <property name="typeName" value="entity.key.AttributeValueKey"/>
                            <property name="affinityKeyFieldName" value="usage_point_code"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="queryEntities">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                <property name="keyType" value="entity.key.AttributeValueKey"/>
                                <property name="valueType" value="READINGS_202204"/>
                                <property name="fields">
                                    <map>
                                        <entry key="balancing_market_party_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="customer_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="dso_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="inbound_file_name" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="inbound_message_orig_id" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="interval_start_day" value="java.sql.Date"/>
                                        <entry key="is_service_delivery_point" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="reading_source_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="reading_time_stamp" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                                        <entry key="reading_time_stamp_tz" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="reported_day" value="java.sql.Date"/>
                                        <entry key="reported_date_time" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                                        <entry key="reported_date_time_tz" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="t_creation_date" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                                        <entry key="t_creation_date_tz" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="usage_point_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="acquired_date_time" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                                        <entry key="acquired_date_time_tz" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="inbound_message_id" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                                        <entry key="dso_tariff_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="forward_active_energy" value="java.lang.Double"/>
                                        <entry key="forward_quality_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="reverse_active_energy" value="java.lang.Double"/>
                                        <entry key="reverse_quality_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="balance_active_energy" value="java.lang.Double"/>
                                        <entry key="balance_quality_code" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                    </map>
                                </property>
                                <property name="keyFields">
                                    <set>
                                        <value>usage_point_code</value>
                                        <value>reading_time_stamp</value>
                                        <value>reading_time_stamp_tz</value>
                                        <value>inbound_file_name</value>
                                    </set>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQVmO.png)

Low CPU load factor just after the servers have started yet to load
I attach to script to run ignite instance server:

```
nohup bash $IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.sh -v \
-server \
-J-DIGNITE_DIRECT_IO_ENABLED=true \
-J- DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true \
-J-Xloggc:/data2/ignite/work/log/GClog.txt \
-J-Xms4g \
-J-Xmx4g \
-J-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch \
-J-XX:+UseG1GC \
-J-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC \
-J-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
-J-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 \
-J-XX:+UseCompressedOops \
-J-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 \
-J-XX:ConcGCThreads=2 \
-J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
/data1/ignite/config/default-config.xml 1> /home/oracle/ignite.log 2>&1 &
```

And crucial snippet code of application to loading data from spark dataframe to cache:

```
val CONFIG = "default-config.xml"


sqlDF.write.format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, CONFIG)
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE, "READINGS_202204")
  //.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_ALLOW_OVERWRITE, true)
  //.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_FLUSH_FREQUENCY, 30000)
  //.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_PER_NODE_PARALLEL_OPERATIONS, 8)
  //.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_PER_NODE_BUFFER_SIZE, 4096)
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, "usage_point_code,reading_time_stamp,reading_time_stamp_tz,inbound_file_name")
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS, "template=partitioned,backups=0,CACHE_NAME=READINGS_202204")
  .save()
```

At the moment I have to create SQL with UNION ALL which doesn't look good, for example:

```
select * from (select * from READINGS_202201 
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202202
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202203 
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202204 
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202205 
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202206
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202207
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202208 
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202209
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202210
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202211
               union all 
               select * from READINGS_202212) 
where usage_point_code='590243874018422425'
```

Any answers are welcome

Best Regards
Dariusz

I tried loading data into a single cache using different settings. Whenever 200-300 million records were loaded, loading more records slowed down significantly. I would like to be able to load 5 or 20 billion records into one cache using three working nodes. Each node has (96GB RAM, 16 core, 6 x 900 GB HDD, Net Card 1Gb/s)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the close vote, saying this isn't a good question format for SO. But here are a few points:

- Three nodes aren't many for multiple billions of records
- You've unnecessarily changed a lot of parameters
- You have slow disks. When it runs out of memory, it will only be as fast as the disks
- Despite having 96Gb of memory on each machine, you've configured Ignite to use only 8Gb. Most of the memory on your host is going to waste

Comment: Thanks Stephen.

On a production environment it will be difficult to allocate more than 7 nodes. I assume that each node will have 40 cores, 20 HDDs, 256GB RAM and 10 Gb/s network cards.
Data acquired will relate to more than 3 million usage pointes. Each of these will be generate 24 readings per day giving the following number of readings to be uploaded over 2 years = 3,000,000 x 24h x 365 days x 2 years = over 52 billion readings.